# How to achieve this with join instead of using a subquery?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How could I change this query bellow to use join instead of a subquery?

```
SELECT ID, Name, UnitPrice
FROM Products
WHERE UnitPrice <
  ( SELECT AVG( UnitPrice ) FROM Products )
ORDER BY UnitPrice DESC;
```

Thanks

Comment: is that what you are looking for??? `select T1.* FRom [dbo].[Table_1] AS T1 INNER JOIN  ( SELECT AVG( Number ) as Number FROM [Table_1] ) AS T2 ON T1.Number < T2.Number`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is to use the window functions

```
;with cte as (
    SELECT ID 
         , Name
         , UnitPrice
         , AvgPrice = avg(UnitPrice) over (Order By (Select NULL))
     FROM Products
)
Select * from cte where UnitPrice<AvgPrice
```

Comment: @Mou The window functions are fantastic, and well worth your time to get comfortable with them.

Comment: Yes, but in this case aren't so efective as comparing with scalar value. In this case of CTE engine have to compute new column for all rows and then compare.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to do it with join as the following:

```
SELECT T1.* 
FROM [dbo].[Table_1] AS T1 
INNER JOIN ( SELECT AVG( Number ) as Number FROM [Table_1] ) AS T2 
ON T1.Number < T2.Number 
ORDER BY T1.UnitPrice DESC;
```

Otherwise use variable to store this value

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with joins on

- With CTE.
- With derivated table.
- With assistant view.
- With assistant temp table.
- With join on grouped subquery.

or can use:

- With variable.
- With table function.
- With cross apply.

But your qry is the clearest solution.

Comment: Clearest depends on whom you are speaking of. Also, the impact on running a query for every row in your query can be degrading significantly. Always treat SQL as a relational language and deal with sets of data when possible.

Comment: I'm speaking of subquery from topic owner. Comparing with scalar value and easy readable.